# Why does FOSUserBundle documentation recommend login$ path

Tags: symfony, fosuserbundle

On this page:  http://symfony.com/doc/master/bundles/FOSUserBundle/index.html

the recommended security.yml has

```
  access_control:
    - { path: ^/login$, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
    - { path: ^/register, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
```

Why is there a $ at the end of /login but not at the end of /register?

On a related note, when I visit `/register` I am redirected to `/register/`.

Answer (score 0):

The access control on the login uses a **regex**. This always means URL starting with **/login**, so /login, /login-check...etc.

The second one allows to catch all the URLs starting with the **directory /register/**

I hope that I have been able to help you with my explanations.

Comment: hmmm - seems like it may be the opposite.  Assuming these paths are regular expressions, then ^/login$ would only match exactly "/login" and not the other urls you mention.  But since /register doesn't have the $ at the end, then /register-check, etc. would be allowed.